# new to c++ need a review on linked list insertion

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am very new to programming and have been trying to insert title in alphabetical order but my insertion function does not seem to been working. Please help!

```
class Book {

public:
    Book() {
    }
    ;
    Book(char *newTitle) {
        strcpy(title, newTitle);
    }

    char *getBook() {
        return title;
    }

    int compareTo(Book *getbook) {
        return (strcmp(title, getbook->title));
    }

private:
    char title[81];

};

void BookList::insert(Book *newBook) {
    BookNode *node = new BookNode(newBook);
    BookNode *current = NULL;
    BookNode *previous = current;

    node->next = NULL;
    current = head;

    if (current == NULL) {
        head = node;
        head->next = NULL;
    }

    else {
        while (current->next != NULL && (newBook->compareTo(current->book) > 0)) {
            previous = current;

            current = current->next;
        }
        node->next = previous->next;
        previous->next = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? In other words, what are the symptoms?

Comment: it didnot print anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not really taking advantage of a linked list with your implementation. Inserting into a linked list should can be an O(1) operation. Very easy and efficient. Simply keep track of the end of your list and you can remove the while loop.

```
class BookList {
public:
    BookNode* head;
    BookNode* end;

    BookList():head(NULL), end(NULL) {}

    void insert(Book data) {
        if(head == NULL) {
            head = new BookNode(data);
            end = head;
        } else {
            end.next = new BookNode(data);
            end = end.next;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
while (current->next != NULL ...
```

should read

```
while (current != NULL ...
```

Can't see any other problems at the moment.